# SAS: while creating XMl Special characters are getting converted (ie from iso-8859-1 to utf-8 format )

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, sas, iso-8859-1

**input xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<XML>
      <individual_first_nm> Dehont </individual_first_nm>
      <individual_gender> M </individual_gender>
      <individual_ba_street> Chaussée Crâhlîs </individual_ba_street>
      <individual_birth_dt_chr> 1954-06-22 </individual_birth_dt_chr>
 </XML>
```

**output xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <PersonData><Name>Dehont</Name><Birth><Date>1954-06-22</Date></Birth><Gender>M</Gender>
    <Address><Street>ChaussÃ©e CrÃ¢hlÃ®s</Street></Address>
    </PersonData>
```

**SAS code used:**

```
 filename infile "&input_path/input.xml" ;                    
 filename style  "&xsl_path./style.xsl" ;                    
 filename outfile "&output_path/output.xml" termstr=crlf encoding='UTF-8';

 proc xsl in=infile xsl=style out=outfile; run;
```

**Desc:**
While applying the schema on input xml, it is converting the special characters into some other format(may be in UTF-8 format).
So, i am not the getting the correct name in the output xml.

i have even tried using encoding='iso-8859-1' but still the the output generated is in UTF-8 format only...

Please suggest how to generate the output xml in "iso-8859-1" format or how we can retain back those special characters.

Comment: can you post the xsl file?  have you tried specifying the encoding on the INFILE reference?

Comment: @DomPazz Yes i have even specified encoding in the infile reference and executed, but still the special characters were getting changed...    And sorry i can't post XSL here.....is there anything that has to be taken care of in XSL file

Comment: I don't have a whole lot of experience with it.  I was asking for the xsl to see if I could make it work.  I would suggest opening a ticket with SAS tech support.